# Disable page resize HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta-tags

I am trying to figure out how to disable the zoom function on a browser where the user can use the keyboard to enlarge text/images. The "Command +" and "Command -" function on the keyboard. How can I disable this function?

I have seen it done with annualreport.elevationchurch.org

Comment: I went to annualreport.elevationchurch.org I can still zoom

Comment: I don't recommend attempting this if it is even possible.  Those functions are there because users want and like them.  If you disable them you will just infuriate the user.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your responses... I guess I will not attempt to do that any longer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using keyboard events to make a null, or pop up saying zoom disabled, event when users hit - or +.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Though that`s not the only way to zoom. You can also use your mouse or on certain browsers click view>zoom in.

I strongly recommend you don`t do that or try to disable zoom.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent a user who stays zoomed in, coming to your site while already in that fashion.  +1 don't try